# Embedding Python within C++ (CPython API)

Tags: python, c++, qt

I'm trying to embed Python within my C++ project (Qt5). My project looks like this:

python_test.pro:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = python_test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Tools\Python\Python35_64\include

LIBS += -LC:\Tools\Python\Python35_64\ -lpython3
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                   "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return a.exec();
}
```

When compiling I get a linker error telling me this: `` main.cpp:-1: Error: undefined reference to `__imp_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags' ``.

The funny thing is that `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` can be found. I read something about the define `Py_LIMITED_API` which hides the function PyRun_SimpleStringFlags. But I don't get it.

How am I supposed to run a Python script/file/string without these functions being available within the C API?

Setup:

- Win7 Prof 64 bit
- Qt 5.5.1
- g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 5.3.0
- Python 3.5.1 64-bit (prebuilt from https://www.python.org/downloads/release)/python-351/)

Comment: It may make a difference if you link `-lpython35` and not `-lpython3`.

Comment: [offtopic] I would suggest to look at `pythonqt` (http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net) it's a really powerful way to bind Qt applications and python (it's PyQt the other way round)

Comment: @bibi I already have taken a look at this library and it seems perfect. But I had problems compiling it/debugging projects with this library included. Tried to contact the developers but didn't get an answer. So I decided to stick to CPython API since I need only to run scripts for converting strings.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on my computer (without Qt though), with `-lpython35` compiling succeeded and with `-lpython3` it did not.

So

```
LIBS += -LC:\Tools\Python\Python35_64\ -lpython35
```

instead of

```
LIBS += -LC:\Tools\Python\Python35_64\ -lpython3
```

Comment: This did the job, thank you! Is it correct that python3 (python3.dll) creates the define Py_LIMITED_API to keep API compatibility over all python 3 versions (3.2, 3.4 etc) ?

Comment: @Burner If you put `#define Py_LIMITED_API` in your source file before `#include <Python.h>`, and then try to compile, you will notice that function *PyRun_SimpleString* won't be available and `python3.dll` corresponds to this limited API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm now facing a problem while deploying my application to another pc. The application starts fine but as soon as a script is executed (PyRun_SimpleString is reached) the application crashes with an error within the file: C:\windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll. The dll is available on all the PCs I'm working at. I don't know what to make of it.